# Popups for checking/unchecking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have prompts that produce a popup when a box is ticked and unticked. There looks to be a line of redundant code, but when removed the functions no longer work. So maybe not so redundant:-) But the #id doesn't match to anything (currently set as CAPS to not match)

Any ideas why this is interfering?

```js
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($("#checkbox").is(':checked')) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to CONFIRM the order?')) {
      $('#CHECKBOX').click();
    }
  }
});

$("#checkbox").on('change', function() {
  this.checked = !this.checked ? !confirm('Do you really want to change this to NOT RECEIVED?') : true;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nd1wj54/1/

Comment: commenting out `$('#CHECKBOX').click();` does not change anything

Comment: I also removed the opening {} that was wrapped around them when I did it, perhaps that would be what broke the function. However if there is nothing there should they not be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you mean

```js
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    this.checked = confirm('Are you sure you want to CONFIRM the order?')); 
  }    
  else {
    this.checked = !confirm('Do you really want to change this to NOT RECEIVED?'); 
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead ids, so now redundant code needed. You can store informations in the `data` attribute of a HTML element. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nd1wj54/2/).

I've add a class to every checkbox what should be examined.

```
$(".checkIt").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    confirm('Do you really want to change ' + $(this).data('id') + ' to NOT RECEIVED?');
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="checkbox1" class="checkIt" />
<input type="checkbox" data-id="checkbox2" class="checkIt" />
<input type="checkbox" data-id="checkbox3" class="checkIt" />
```

Comment: on click is a better event in my opinion. Some browsers need a blur to trigger change

Comment: tell me a browser like this.

Comment: For sure some older ones. See [older spec -  change](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-change): _A control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event type shall be dispatched before the event type blur._

Comment: You gave me the specification, not a browser. I bet that 99.9% of the todays brwosers know the change, even IE9 ( i do not have, can not test)

Comment: But who cares if click does the same without the possibility of failing in any browser? Our site has 10% IE8 visitors still